# Is it possible to find amount of data that come and go through HBA ports?

Tags: centos, io, port, traffic, san

I have a ProLiant server with a HBA card (2 ports).

```
$ ls /sys/class/fc_host  
host2  host3
```

and also I have a 20T SAN storage that is connected to San switch via those ports. Is it possible to monitor my HBA ports and find the amount of data that went through those HBA ports?

For example: I had 2GB data IO from `host2` in 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking in /sys/class/fc_host/host[1|2]/statistics. In early days that worked for Emulex FC HBAs.